# The blind leading the blind

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is undeniably an authority on coding and other technical things, but Buddhism isn't like intellectual disciplines where knowledge makes you an authority. Buddhist teachings are an expedient to get us to enlightenment (as per the metaphors of the menu and the meal, the finger and the moon etc.). Intellectual understanding of the teachings is not the point.

A reasonable degree of enlightenment is considered a sine qua non for teaching in most schools. If you aren't enlightened, how can you possibly guide others to enlightenment? What's the use of parroting dogma you haven't realised the import of (especially if you do so with a big reputation and an air of authority)? Are you helping people or misleading them?

Comment: Are you asking for information, asking for an answer? This seems a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question): is it intended as a criticism of the whole site's existence, of one or two specific answers, or of some specific users? If you were to rephrase your statement as a suggestion for improvement instead of as a question, what would you say: are you saying that people on this site are misleading, and that (instead of using this site) everyone who isn't enlightened should instead find a teacher with a reasonable degree of enlightenment, who teaches in a school?

Comment: You tagged this topic [tag:discussion] but I don't know what you want to discuss. Some topics on meta discuss *questions* ("what's a good or bad kind of question on this site?"), and sometimes topics discuss *answers* ("what's a good or bad answer?"), and sometimes *comments*, and sometimes *users*. But the way you started your topic, do you want to discuss whether "Buddhism" (perhaps instead of e.g. "enlightenment") is an appropriate subject for a stack exchange site?

Comment: Or the word "authority" appears three times in what you wrote. Is your question then about authority: is it something to do with "authority" that you want people, that you're asking people, to try to answer?

Comment: Do you disagree with any of the points? Authorisation is important. In most schools monks spend many years training before they teach. Here any self-appointed expert can teach. Doesn't that strike you as incongruous? Why is authorisation to teach handled so stringently in traditional schools?

Comment: I think that, maybe, if I were to disagree, it would be because I was answering a different question. I guess you're fixed on a question (or if not a question, an axiom) like, "Is a teacher important? Enlightenment? Authority?", and you're answering that. If I were to "disagree", by giving a different answer, that might be because I was answering a different question: for example, "Why questions and answers on Stack Exchange? What kinds of questions, what kinds of answers? What are benefits and/or limitations of Stack Exchange as a format/medium?"

Comment: 'What kinds of question, what kinds of answer' would be a good starting point for a new discussion.

Comment: Do you want me to try to answer this question anyway? Or are you content that you've had your say on the subject? Do you want to start a new discussion (as a different [meta-topic](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)), do you want me to try to start one for you? Are you more interested in what *questions* can be asked, or are you more interested in how to *answer* questions without misleading people?

Comment: i don't know how many people are turning to stackexchange for enlightenment, probably quite a few ha.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are several misunderstandings here.

First, I wouldn't say Stack Exchange is any authority on coding or programming. It's useful, with grains of salt, at best. Not different from this one.

Second, you say that there's a purpose to Buddhism as declared by the Buddha and challenge the appropriateness of this site to *guide people to enlightenment*. You also say that intellectual understanding of the teachings is not the point (the purpose) of Buddhism. I fully agree with these words, and I believe many (perhaps most) users here agree too.

However, you seem to imply that this site (and/or people here) are guiding and teaching others to enlightenment. You also seem to imply that knowledge seems pointless in this endeavor, and that an unenlightened person should not be occupied with sharing information until he has accomplished the goal. Finally, you seem to assume that only people interested in enlightenment come here to participate.

If the above is a correct assessment, all these points are not true nor beneficial.

- While some people here may think of themselves as teachers and may think of their questions and answers as teaching, others write questions and answers just with the intent of obtaining and sharing information so they can better inform themselves and other readers, absent the presumption of guiding people to enlightenment.
- as pretty much any other activity, intellectual knowledge of the Dharma is a requisite for the practice of Buddhism. Knowledge, indeed, has a larger role than assumed, regardless if one is just a practitioner or a scholar. Moreover, this knowledge not only can be shared, clarified and discussed through language and ordinary words, but (as far as we understand the history) have been done pretty much like this by the Buddha and his disciples.
- It's a fantasy to expect that only enlightened people can teach anything Buddhism and everyone else should be silent about all of it. Normal people can certainly clarify things like what the noble path is, what is meant by first noble truth, and what are the seven factors of enlightenment without being enlightened. The same goes for any other field: it's a fantasy to expect to be taught mathematics only by fully graduated mathematicians when a non-mathematician on our side can help us with something we don't understand.
- *Buddhism* is not only a means to enlightenment: it's more than "*Dharma*". It's a (or perhaps many) religion and cultural phenomenon. It has a history. It embodies philosophies. It has been written in ancient languages. It spawned forms of art (sculpture, paintings, poetry, etc). All of these are embraced by intellectual fields of investigation. A buddhist practitioner may think less of these things, but it's not on his/her power to prevent people from being interested and study them.

So, one way of thinking about this S.E. site is as an authoritative guide for awakening. Which is not.

Another way, which I personally find preferable, is a useful site where people can raise questions and get some information or initial pointers for further investigation, be them buddhists expecting to clarify a doctrinal or practical point, be them non-buddhist expecting to clarify their understanding of the religion, be historians, buddhologists, art history students, philosophers, etc.

Comment: Buddhism isn't like Mathematics in that respect. You need to know where the noble eightfold path leads to clarify what it really is, otherwise all you can do is parrot what you've read in books. I'm not saying that knowledge is pointless, I'm saying that advice about the meal from someone who hasn't yet eaten is pointless. All Buddhist practitioners and scholars have contributions to make, but you shouldn't assume the mantle of a dharma teacher if you're not one. Shakyamuni shared his seat with Makakasho and not Ananda for a reason.

Comment: I also think that SE Buddhism paints and overly intellectual picture of Buddhism. Buddhism is primarily a practice carried out in a sangha under the guidance of a teacher, but I've only seen one answer suggesting that the questioner seeks out a monastery/practice centre. That should be the default answer to almost every question - **find a local centre and ask a teacher**.

Comment: Well, "parroting" is precisely how the suttas (and Buddhism itself) survived :) -- I'm sorry this site falls short of your ideal of how all matters of Buddhism should be engaged and that you think all participation here should restrict themselves to tell people to find a center and a teacher.

Comment: Parroting isn't how Buddhism survived, that's the point of the Makakasho/Ananda reference - Ananda knew the sutras by heart (he's the 'I' in 'Thus have I heard...') but he wasn't the Buddha's successor as he wasn't enlightened.

Comment: @GavinSerra sorry I wasn't clearer. The "parroting" I alluded to was a reference to the tradition of verbatim memorization and repetition of the suttas. But please understand, myself coming from the Zen tradition, that I'm sensitive to your concerns . However, this site really is just another internet site, where people subject to mistakes come to participate. Some may join and use it for teaching and even come across as self promoting,  dogmatic and disrespectful. But others here are just interested in getting some pointers or pointing out some directions to others looking for one.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give some extra perspectives from other S.E. religion sites:

## Christianity

In the Christianity S.E. site, they [discourage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "advice on how to handle certain situations (pastoral advice questions)". They [discussed this issue and even upvoted a standard comment message](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing) to questions that seek such advices in their meta site.

## Judaism

In the Judaism  S.E. site, they adopted an [information box](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/actualizing-avodah-shebalev) with a disclaimer where it says:

[image]

## Islam

In the [Islam S.E. help cente](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)r, they added a more serious warning:

> It is also important to note that this is not a fatwa site. While questions on the legality of actions (from an Islamic perspective) are welcome, answers may be posted by anybody regardless of training or expertise. It is important to judge the evidences provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at your own risk.

Comment: ah great answer, which complicates my view i expressed below. hmm. do we have any such equivalent message, on this site??

Comment: Hi. I don't think we have messaging here.

Answer (score 2):

I have felt the same way at times, and the answer about "excess of personality" maybe also. But over a long stretch of time, reading many questions and answers and comments, I see this more as a sangha, with great people in it. My respect for them has grown.

People learn in different ways, and although SE in general is mostly conscious / verbal / rational thought process, the more feeling oriented way is hard to put in to a web site, but is understood and respected here. I don't think anyone is saying that words and book knowledge are sufficient, but at least here they are available, interactively (by being able to ask questions).

Many times I have said "please seek out a meditation teacher." Nothing can stand in for that.

Comment: that's a good attitude.

Comment: i like the idea of assuming that other people are sincere and have things in common with you. but, it often seems people want to demonstrate --
 what -- dogmatic dismissal of anything they didn't feel a connection to yet? we have 2,500 years of tradition and its adherents, many of whom are saints, dharmaheirs, have defeated death... so, be careful :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a viable concern. With the internet being so pervasive etc., many people will turn to sites like stackexchange not just to find out about Buddhism, but for enlightenment.

But, the former is what the site is about, and I personally think that it's OK, that those who have studied Buddhism, even just a little, can tell us what about what they "know".

For what it's worth, my bugbear about the site is the excess of personality. The nature of the medium means people are going to be here to promote their own peculiar beliefs etc., as well as try to put down opposing views (see what I did there?). That's why the voting system is so important, and I urge anyone who has voting privileges to vote down any answer which implies that Buddhism is categorically this, despite what many of its proponents have claimed, over the course of its life.

Comment: Right. A car is about getting somewhere. The MotorVehicles SE doesn't get you anywhere, and few of the contributors are Master Mechanics, but it is still a useful site.