# "Is Buddhism for me?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

Recently, this question was posted: [Possible Potential Buddhist](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23866/possible-potential-buddhist).

I guess the poster is asking if he/she should take the Buddhist path or not. If so, it seems too personal to me to be useful for the broad public.

Opinions?

PS: perhaps this is also related to [Which type of Buddhism is for me?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/which-type-of-buddhism-is-for-me)

Comment: Then don't answer it! The question Isn't going to hurt you. What good are you doing here? PERSONAL QUESTIONS ARE THE ONLY USEFUL QUESTIONS.

Comment: Hi @Lowbrow, I came bf. the community to get opinions about the question referred above. I'm not sure it's clear, but that's also what meta is for, to discuss policy. This inquiry is a follow up to the 7-vote [post](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/the-blind-leading-the-blind/2129#2129) that shows how other religion S.E. sites regard (very?) "personal advice" questions (policies they also discussed on their own). I invite you to vote on or provide your own answer (e.g. "I think it's on topic") as a more effective means to influence the direction of B.S.E  site. With metta

Comment: @Lowbrow I think the meta-question here is because it's technically NOT a question, isn't personal (i.e. doesn't detail the person's situation), and isn't explicitly asking anything about Buddhism either.

Answer (score 1):

The question is literally "iam at a crossroads in life and iam not certain in which direction I should take".

IMO the self-description in the question is, at least superficially, not very informative -- it boxes the compass, from physics to the supernatural -- and neither is the description of the crossroads in question.

- I am [reluctant to close](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) a question, but for the reasons above I find it hard to think how to write a personalised answer that addresses the specific situation of the OP (i.e. that responds to the question).

  Perhaps we'd get some insight (into what question the OP is asking) by asking for a specific question about Buddhism: with a question mark and everything, in the title and in the text.
- Or (though I won't try to do this immediately) someone might form an impression of the OP by reading their other question and their other six answers on this site (and/or their other posts on other sites) to guess what aspect of Buddhism may or may not interest them.
- Another approach to an answer (with perhaps only slim chance of relevance) might be to dig into the second of the three paragraphs in the OP -- to explain what Buddhism might say about that.